# Getting a role through Discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

Good day. I am new to python programming, I am creating my bot for a server in discord via the discord.pi library. I need the bot to moderate the messages on the server and for the words that are included in the list it assigns a bad role to the offender. I coped with the moderation of messages, he finds the right words, but there is a problem with the issue of the role. I tried many variants of the code for issuing a role, but they all led to an error when the bot tried to issue a role. Most often this was due to the fact that the creators of this library changed everything in many places. How can I solve my problem.

I have attached only the role issuance code:

```py
import discord
import asyncio
from discord import utils
import config

authorper = str
messageper = str
member = authorper

class MyClient(discord.Client):
    async def on_ready(self): 
        print('We have logged in as {0}!'.format(self.user))

    async def on_message(self, message):
        member = ctx.guild.get_member(int(ab))
        var = discord.utils.get(message.guild.roles, name = config.ROLE)
        await member.add_role(var)

#RUN
client = MyClient()
client.run(config.TOKEN)
```

Comment: What is `config.ROLE`? Why are you not passing the name/ID instead?

Comment: " How can I solve my problem." - what is your *problem*? The question is very unclear

Answer (score 0):

You can add a role by doing `await member.add_roles(var)`

Make sure you have enabled intents in your code and enabled in discord developer settings as `member` would be None.